# date parse giving wrong date in android

Tags: java, android, date

In android, I am getting the wrong date when parsing. I am providing `22 Feb (Wednesday)`. Why is it giving me the wrong week day (Sunday)? Check the screenshot below to see the full code with values.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM (EEEE)");
try {
    Date date = format.parse(strDate);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    String output = format.format(c.getTime());
    tvDeliveryDate.setText(output);
    tvDeliveryTime.setText(time);
    deliveryDateTime = output + "," + time;
    db.putString("deliver_date",output);
    db.putString("deliver_time",time);
    db.putString("deliver_date_time",output + ", " + time);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: Screenshot Image]

Comment: Please share whats going wrong? year? describe

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM (EEEE) YYYY"); try using this

Comment: or you need to pass parameter strDate in function with year

Comment: thanks adding yyyy worked for me..  not YYYY

Comment: sorry my mistake its yyyy. Happy to help you :) :)

Answer (score 5):

Your date format doesn't have a year component, so 1970 is assumed. In 1970, February 22 was a Sunday.

From the [`SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) documentation:

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a `Date`. All of the calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any missing date-time information. For example, the year value of the parsed `Date` is 1970 with `GregorianCalendar` if no year value is given from the parsing operation.